# How to prevent VoiceOver from focusing on the content behind a modal

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I have a modal and I don't want voiceover to read the content behind it. Setting `aria-modal=true` should've been enough but then I saw that VoiceOver does not support this behaviour out of the box like better screen readers like NVDA and JAWS.

https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/aria-modal_attribute#support-table-2

And it says that authors can implement this functionality on their own for VoiceOver. I have successfully trapped the keyboard focus inside the modal (using the tab key) with JS but voiceover is going behind the content when I use the arrow keys. How can I achieve this? My modal is structured like this:-

```
    <div
      role="dialog"
      aria-modal="true"
      aria-labelledby="title"
      aria-describedby="description"
      tabindex="-1"
    >
      <div class="sticky-header">
        <h2 id="title" class="title">
          This is a heading
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p id="description">
          This is a paragraph.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="sticky-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <a href="#">
          Proceed
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does your JS look like? Have you tried setting focus on the modal using `element.focus()` ?

Comment: @Josh I'm setting the focus on modal when it opens using the `.focus()` method and I'm also locking the tab and shift+tab operations inside the modal so that the focus doesn't go out using the keyboard. Everything is working fine with other screen readers. This is a VoiceOver problem. The question essentially becomes - "How can I make everything except that modal invisible to the screen reader while the modal is open?"

Comment: Essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100125/ive-implemented-a-custom-dialog-using-react-native-papers-dialog-component-but/72104950#72104950.  That question was asking about React but it's really a general dialog question just like this one.

Comment: As best as I can tell, your modal is constructed properly and this is a bug in VoiceOver. You can choose to try other solutions, like Slugolicious suggestion above to make the modal siblings with the main section of your page, or doing something with a live-region. If it were me, I probably wouldn't design around the bug unless it's really necessary to the specific needs of your audience. Some may disagree with me on that. Your approach may depend on the amount of resources you have on your team to implement and then revert workaround techniques. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174667

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. With voice over the user can "click" outside and swipe out of the dialog. I believe this is a issue with VoiceOver, and I could not find any solution on the web. It's not the best solution but what I ended up with was to add a boolean to the open/close dialog event. Then use the boolean with aria-hidden

```
<div [attr.aria-hidden]="IsMenuOpen">content behind menu</div>

<button (click)="openMenu(); isMenuOpen = !isMenuOpen" ></button>
```

Comment: I am trying this but the voiceover focus still goes on the content behind it (like the <header> and <footer> tags and the links and text inside those tags.

Comment: you can add [attr.aria-hidden] to the footer and header. aria-hidden will effect the header/footer and all html inside the fotter(child).

Answer (score 0):

am not a good UI export but its a bit suggestion
please try these attributes I hope you'll get better solution.

My solution is:
role="alertdialog" aria-modal="true"